# Unidirectionality of Time in Spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, causality, arrow-of-time

I have a question regarding the dimension of time. We all know that an event in spacetime is defined by a point

$$ {x}^{u} = (ct, x, y, z) .$$

The only component that breaks the symmetry is $ct$, which is why the metric tensor has diagonal components equal to $(-1,1,1,1)$.

Why is it not possible to move in both directions in the $ct$ dimension? I've heard that it's because at the beginning, when $t \to 0$, the four dimensions were symmetric, but due to spontaneous symmetry breaking, particles took one dimension to move at the speed of light (all particles, both fermionic and bosonic, move in spacetime at the speed of light). That dimension contracted spatially, leaving a tangent hyperplane (actually a volume in $x, y, z$) that we know as space, which allows movement in all directions $x, -x, y, -y, z, -z$. But the dimension that contracted only allows us to move in the direction of $ct$ and not $-ct$. Is this correct? Is there any theory about this? I've heard this from Brian Greene.

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard that it's because at the beginning, when t \to 0, the four dimensions were symmetric, but due to spontaneous symmetry breaking, particles took one dimension to move at the speed of light (all particles, both fermionic and bosonic, move in spacetime at the speed of light). That dimension contracted spatially, leaving a tangent hyperplane (actually a volume in x, y, z) that we know as space, which allows movement in all directions x, -x, y, -y, z, -z. But the dimension that contracted only allows us to move in the direction of ct and not -ct.

None of this is necessary.

> Why is it not possible to move in both directions in the ct dimension?

This can be understood by looking at the meaning of the spacetime interval. In an inertial frame you have $$\Delta s^2 = -c^2 \Delta t^2 + \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2$$

Consider the locus of all events with $\Delta s^2 = 1$, which is called a spacelike interval. This is a hyperboloid of one sheet, meaning all of the events are topologically connected. So there exists a smooth transformation from any event with $\Delta s^2 = 1$ to any other.
[image: Hyperboloid of one sheet]

Consider now the locus of all events with $\Delta s^2 = -1$, which is called a timelike interval. This is a hyperboloid of two sheets. Meaning that half of the events are topologically disconnected from the other half. If we look carefully we will see that one connected half consists of events that are all at a time after the origin, this is the future sheet. The other connected half consists of events that are all at a time before the origin, this is the past sheet. There does not exist a smooth transformation from any event in the future sheet to any event in the past sheet.
[image: Hyperboloid of two sheets]

Note, this does not "prefer" future over past in any way. Everything is still symmetric under a (non-smooth) time reversal transformation $t \rightarrow -t$. But it does separate future from past. So it is not possible to move in both directions simply because these are completely sets of events. There is no way to smoothly transform from future to past.

This makes it impossible to move in both directions in time because of energy, momentum, and mass. Similarly to events in spacetime and the spacetime interval, there is also the following relationship $$m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p_x^2-p_y^2 - p_z^2$$ Similarly, this produces hyperboloids of one sheet and two sheets. For a particle going "forwards" in time to begin going "backwards" in time it would not be able to keep its mass constant. There is no smooth transformation that accomplishes this.

Comment: Thanks but what do you means by "There is no way to smoothly transform from future to past." I can't get it.

Comment: @julianoviedo If you want to rotate a vector by 10 degrees, you can break that into an infinite number of infinitesimal rotations. That is smooth. Find any two vectors on the future hyperboloid, they can be connected with a smooth path, an infinite number of infinitesimal changes. But not to the past hyperboliod. There would be a finite jump at some part of the path.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand. The question should have been why all bodies have a displacement in the ct component and not in x, y, or z

Answer (score 0):

The laws of physics are, as far as we know, invariant if we reverse the direction of time and at the same time invert parity (left/right) and replace matter with antimatter - this is called [CPT symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry). The reason we "feel" that time "moves" in only one direction is that the universe itself is asymmetric in time - the Big Bang was a state of especially *low* entropy. So why do we say the Big Bang was in the past and not in the future ? Because in a universe that is asymmetric in time we must experience the past as the direction of time in which entropy decreases, and the future as the direction of time in which entropy increases.

If the universe ever reaches an equilibrium state of maximum entropy then past, future and the passage of time will cease to have any meaning, as any possible sequence of events will be equally likely to occur in either direction.